Older sci fi movie, mindless kids
I barely remember anything about the movie, but I do remember that there was a dark dimly lit street and all the houses were the same, there was no color or outside world, just the street. And there was a boy, a teenager maybe, and he was zombie like and mindless and there was a basketball hoop and a ball but he wasn't playing, just standing there. And there might have been one kid, possibly a girl, who was awake and not mindless.
It was a very strange movie and I saw it around 2003 or 2004 but at the time it seemed older.

This is very reminiscent of a section of the book "A Wrinkle in Time" by  Madeleine L'Engle.  It was made into a TV movie that was released in 2003.  Here is the link to the movie's Wikipedia page.  Since I did not see the TV movie, I can't be sure if the scene you're describing was in it or not, but since the TV movie is based on the book that scene might very well be in it.
A summary of this chapter of the book on sparknotes.com says this:

In Camazotz, every house is the exact same size, shape, and color. In front of each house, children bounce balls ... in a synchronized rhythm that seems to govern the whole town.

